# iOS MDM Certificate Expiration

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm, csr

1) When a push notification certificate is renewed, how does a device with profile already installed update the certificate details in the device's profile?

2) When renewing the APNs certificate we are asked to upload the VendorSignedCSR. Should it be the same VendorSignedCSR used to generate that .pem file?

3) What happens when Vendor's p12 expires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.If the push notification certificate is renewed the push topic remains the same so the device is still able to receive the push notifications. But if you create a new one, the push topic changes and the device has to be re-enrolled.

2.Yes the CSR should be the same unless the vendor renewed their MDM certificate.

3.When the vendors p12 expires and  vendor creates a new one the VendorSignedCSR changes.

Comment: So, when the VendorSignedCSR changes, won't there be any problem while renewing the certificate?

Comment: @SudharshRam The Vendor has to update the signing certificate to reflect the new MDM certificate and there won't be any problem while renewing the certificate.

Comment: Thank you. Can u please check my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027114/ios-mdm-app-installation-cancellation-response