# iOS MDM App Installation/Cancellation Response

Tags: ios, installation, apple-push-notifications, mdm, cancellation

I have developed an MDM Server using the iOS APNS method and I am pushing apps to mobile devices.

I want the MDM Server to know when the App was successfully installed or when the user cancels the alert for App Installation.

I issue the InstallApplication command and I get an Acknowledgement with State as Queued but I want an acknowledgement when the State is Installed.
I tried to issue an ManagedApplicationList command after the InstallApplication command so that I can check if the app installed is now managed thereby concluding that the app was successfully installed. But I get the Acknowledgement with State as Prompting for this command as this command is issued immediately after InstallApplication command.

According to [Mobile Device Management Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/MobileDeviceManagementProtocolRef/3-MDM_Protocol/MDM_Protocol.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017387-CH3-SW52), there are states like - UserRejected, UpdateRejected, ManagementRejected but I never got those responses but this seems like the response I'm expecting.

1) How do I get Acknowledgement when the app was installed successfully?

2) How do I get notified when user cancels the App installation alert?

3) Is there a way to install the app without prompting an alert to the user?

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue when building TestMDM.

1) The InstallApplication command gets acknowledged, which indicats the phone received the command. I worked around this by using the ManagedApplicationList command with the BundleId of the app in the Identifiers array. I execute this request once every few seconds and it returns the state of the app I'm trying to install.

2) You should end up with a UserRejected status if the user opts to not install your app.

3) I believe the only way to silently install apps is on a Supervised device.

Comment: I think Executing ManagedApplicationList every few seconds is not a good idea. If there are many devices managed, then a lot of push notifications has to be sent.

Comment: My use case is very different, so it’s not a problem for me. I don’t have any other suggestions I’m afraid. Their implementation makes perfect sense, since it might be some time before the user acknowledges the installation.

Comment: Probably, the device can communicate with the server after user acknowledges the request. Apple could have done something like that.

Comment: They don't do anything unsolicited, so the iOS device will only answer a request. If it was asynchronous, the MDM would have more complicated to implement in some circumstances.

Comment: Tomas has the correct answer.  The current MDM protocol that Apple implements relies heavily on servers doing their own polling (for both app install & software updates) & determining how often they want to poll is left to the server. The MDM client will ensure it gives you back those final states of UserRejected, UpdateRejected, ManagementRejected one one of those polls eventually (after which the state will disappear as Apple assumes you've recorded it once you've seen it). Current MDM protocol has no feedback channel & so is limited by what it had when it was first released many years back.